# When copying files, windows tries to delete files already present, how do I stop this?

Tags: windows-10, file-transfer

I have a trail camera with a video I want to move to my PC.  On the PC are some other trail cam videos recorded on other days.  When I try to move the new video over to the folder on the PC, either via copy/paste or by dragging it over, I get two dialogs.  One showing how long moving the new file will take, one saying how long deleting the 4 files already on my PC will take.  I can tell it is those files it's referring to because the number is the same.  I don't want to delete the old files, how do I stop this?

EDIT:

Here is a screenshot of the dialogs.  I get it whenever I try to move files from my trail camera to my folder on my PC or when I try to move files from the trail cam folder on my PC to an external hard-drive.

100MEDIA is the name of the folder on the trail cam, Opossum is the name of the folder on the PC.

[image]

Comment: Is it because they are identically named? You can usually persuade cameras to not re-start their numbering sequence over each time their existing content is deleted. That would be the smart way to do it.

Comment: Windows, AFAIK, does *not* show a dialog for *deletion* time. Is that dialog from your camera's software? Could you include a screenshot of that dialog?

Comment: @Tetsujin No, they are not identically named.  Also if it was a naming issue, I would expect to get a dialog asking if it should overwrite, and it would also only be one file, not all four.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I am worried about trying it again, I don't want to lose these videos.  Last time I tried it, the delete dialog was at 85% complete.

Comment: Copy (not move) the old files somewhere safe first. Test again

Comment: After your edit - that's usually an option in the media importer, whether or not to delete images from the camera/card after import. It makes no sense that it would attempt this on already imported data when copying to another drive, unless you specified Move not Copy.

Comment: @Tetsujin I did not specify Move not Copy.  It happens when I click-and-drag or when I copy-and-paste.

Comment: You're going to have to test it thoroughly. Duplicate your data first, or just make sure your backup is up to date. Then test what actually happens. Does it move? Does it clean the card? We don't really know yet what is *actually* happening.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're mis-reading the dialog and nothing untoward is occurring.

When you move a file there are two operations that occur:

1. Copy the file from the source to the destination
2. Delete the file from the source

Copying only performs the first part, leaving the file in duplicate in both places.

What I believe you're seeing is not the file being deleted from the target, but from the source as part of the normal move process.

Note: In any move or copy situation, you will receive a very clear prompt where file names are in conflict, and you will have to make a clear indicating of what is to occur for each file.

Evidence: The reason I believe this is what is occurring is that 100Media is a folder similar to DCIM found on camera storage devices. It is not a folder found commonly on a computer or other storage device.